# Can not write to PPAS logfile

Tags: postgresql-performance, pgpool, enterprisedb, postgres-plus

Now, I am testing query from application to PPAS via PgPool.

When I query

```
select a.name, b.name from tb_01 a, tb_02 c where a.id = b.id_ref
```

... or update/insert, I have to wait for a long time (30 --> 60 seconds).

I check in my PPAS log file but I can not find any information about this query.

Example:

- Query (*)
- Complete affter waiting for 30 seconds.
- View log file (dont see any info)

I tested with another query, and it's ok, I can find info in log file.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, what's "PPAS"? Do you mean EnterpriseDB's PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server, their proprietary PostgreSQL variant?

Comment: @CraigRinger: sry :)    PPAS = Enterprisedb PostgreSQL Plus Advanced Server.  I will try. Thanks .

Comment: Remember to include `select version()`. It's OK to ask EnterpriseDB questions under the `postgresql` tag but please also tag `enterprisedb` or `postgres-plus` (I'll be making them tag synonyms soon).

Comment: Nice day to all of you. Thanks all !